# <p:overlayPanel> shows blank white after updating via command link/button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am looking for solution that `p:overlayPanel` content should update it self while clicking `commendButton` or `commendLink`. But its showing blank white `p:overlayPanel` when i click the button. The updating with the `p:overlayPanel` id in that button or link. I have tried many ways nothing worked out. Is my code  wrong? 
Please suggest some solution.

Here is my code :

```
    <ui:repeat id="profiles" value="#{items.lstProfiles}" var="profile">
       <p:commandLink id="profileLink" value="show" update="moviePanel"
                      actionListener="#{dashBoardController.showProfileOverlay}"/>

       <p:overlayPanel id="moviePanel" for="profileLink"  hideEffect="fade"     
                       dynamic="true" style="width:300px; height: 150px;">
           <h:panelGrid columns="2">
               <h:outputText value="Name : "/>
               <h:outputText value="#{dashBoardController.selectedProfile.name}"/>
           </h:panelGrid>
       </p:overlayPanel>
  </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Where do you update the overlay?

Comment: Done already.  Forgot to include in the code here.

Comment: Try without dynamic and does it work without a ui:repeat

Comment: That ui:repeat changes the situation a little, see my update

Answer (score 1):

Usually `dynamic="true"` should do the job but some times it fails.So to update the contents inside the Overlay.
There are many ways to do this by tweaking Jquery.

Simplest one I can think of is:
Since `ui:repeat` generates dynamic ID for `p:overlayPanel`s you can update by providing unique css class name from every iteration.

In Primefaces you can select a component using css class also using: `@(.myclass)`.

And so you can update that component also:- `update="@(.mystyle)"`

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat var="patient" value="#{dataCenter.patientList}">
        <p:commandLink value="#{patient.firstName}" id="patientNameLnk" update="@(.overlay-class-#{patient.patientId})"/><br/>

        <p:overlayPanel for="patientNameLnk">
            <h:panelGroup styleClass="overlay-class-#{patient.patientId}">
                #{patient.firstName}
                #{patient.lastName}
                #{patient.dob}
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

In the above example css class name for every `h:panelGroup` will be generated as `overlay-class-<PATIENT_ID>` so every `h:panelGroup` will have unique class name(if patientId is unique).

Note: Note that I'm updating `h:panelGroup` inside `p:overlayPanel` because if you update `p:overlayPanel` then it might start flickering(it happened to me while executing above example).